# Black nontransparent glass (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am modeling plane and I don't want to model a cockpit so I want to use black windows which will reflect a lot of light but you can't see thought.

Currently I just use Glossy BSDF (GGX) with almost black color (0.01, 0.01, 0.01) and Rougness 0.015 but it don't look quite right. It lacks glass shine and looks too matt.

**Edit:**

Here is my simplified blend file:

[image]

Also here is what i want. Glass on this tie fighter is blackish and it looks like glass. In my blend file it looks more like plastic.

[image: Tie fighter black glass example]

One more thing i noticed is when light reflect from glass whole glass section reflect same amount of light. It can be seen on tie fighter example above.

Comment: What lighting do you have? Also, it might be too high of a roughness value

Comment: If you don't want to see through, why do you need a glass shader then? use a glossy black shader. But the issue you have, I suspect, is that you have a highly reflective object but no environment to reflect...

Comment: I don't need glass shader i need it to look like glass. Problem with current solution is that if i set color to pure black (0,0,0) there is no reflection at all (well that's how black color works) same with roughness. If i set roughness to 0 also no reflection. I don't care about reflections from other object but about light reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a glossy/diffuse mix with the fresnel or layer weight node as the mix factor. This is basically the same thing as the glass shader, but without any transmission. You can actually remove the diffuse shader entirely and leave the first input blank if you want. It'll be a bit less realistic but you get a darker black.[image]