# Creating a glass like material without it being transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Any tips on creating a material that will be easily reconized as glass, without it showing anything behind it? (0 transparency). I'm making a vehicle that has glass windows, but I don't want to make the interior, so I need something glass like that will not show what is behind the glass.

Comment: If it wasn't transparent it would be a solid colour?...

Comment: Maybe dark glossy?

Comment: I vote to reopen this question as the node set up presented in the original answer (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42219/black-nontransparent-glass-cycles) doesn't produce the clean glass effect (in some camera angle views the glass becomes black).

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve it using the ***Backfacing*** output of a ***Geometry*** node as a factor for mixing the *Diffuse* and *Glossy* nodes.
[image]

Set up the *material nodes* as pictured below.
[image]

Remember to set the *Diffuse* shader color to *pure white* and the *Glossy* shader *Roughness* value to *0.000*. In the .gif above I added a blueish tint to the *Glossy* shader's color to make the glass plane visible, but if you want to recreate the look of the *Glass* shader set up the color to pure white.
[image]